# UIButton flashing animation

Tags: ios, animation, uikit

I was wondering if it was possible to apply a flashing animation to a UIButton. I have searched but only found the code for a pulse animation which changes the size of my UIButton continuously. I instead was thinking about some kind of flashing animation to alert the user he has to press the button. The only approach to the problem  I can think of is by changing the alpha constantly using:

```
[self setAlpha:0.5];
```

...but it won't be as visible as a flashing button.

Comment: Have you tried using two buttons( or one dummy image over your button) and hiding/showing it whenever required?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps not the best way, and doesn't really allow you to stop the flashing... but this is simple, works, and does not hinder user interaction:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self flashOn:myButton];
}

- (void)flashOff:(UIView *)v
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.05 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
        v.alpha = .01;  //don't animate alpha to 0, otherwise you won't be able to interact with it
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self flashOn:v];
    }];
}

- (void)flashOn:(UIView *)v
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.05 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
        v.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self flashOff:v];
    }];
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the code by using the `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` animation option. Moreover, if you don't want to loop the animation forever, call `setAnimationRepeatCount:` from inside of the animation block.

Comment: By using your code and turning UIview to UIBarButtonItem i get the error: property alpha not found on object of type UIBarButtonItem

Comment: That is because UIBarButtonItem is not a subclass of UIView.  You said you had a UIButton you wanted to flash, which is indeed a subclass of UIView.

Comment: You likely need to stop `flashOn:` from getting called in the completion handlers if `finished` is `NO` or you will end up in **trouble**.

Answer (score 5):

Reading all the answers so far I found following solution. It repeats a number of times and does the job for me.

```
CGFloat oldAlpha = v.alpha;
CGFloat minAlpha = 0.2;
enum UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut;

[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:0.3 options:options animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:4];
    v.alpha = minAlpha;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    v.alpha = oldAlpha;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise code. If you want the button to fade immediately upon tap, set v.alpha=minAlpha before the animation block, and set the one that is inside the block to 1.0 or to oldAlpha. I find it to look a little more like the user triggered the animation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

call this method when you want blink/flash the button

```
blinkTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(toggleButtonImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and write this method

```
- (void)toggleButtonImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{

    if(toggle)
    {
        [blinkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonImage.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [blinkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonImage1.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    toggle = !toggle;

}
```

in .h write this one

```
NSTimer *blinkTimer;
BOOL toggle;
```

and invalidate the timer where you want to stop the flashing/blinking

```
[blinkTimer invalidate];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could have two different .png files [buttons] that cycle back and forth in a loop, assign the same action to them, and have this kick off whenever a certain condition is met. I'd write the code out but it would likely be full of errors. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: you mean swopping an image? I thought of doing something gradual, a gradual decrease in brightness

Comment: Oh you mean like a pulsing kind of look? Hm. Ray Wenderlich has an interesting tutorial on making a clone of the app "Clear". It's a to do list app. Anyways, he accomplishes a color fade programmatically for the UITableViewCell's. I'd check out that project, and see if you can use the same color principles as he does there. Again, this is just off the top of my head.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13

Comment: Yep, that's the one! I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I did this by creating my own control, subclassing UIControl since Apple doesn't recommend screwing with the view hierarchy of UIButton. I add a background imageView representing the standard background image of the button, and a "glowing" imageView above the background to represent the lit-up state, and toggle its opacity to make it pulse.

I additionally toggle the layer's shadow opacity to make it glow.

**Initializing Code:**

```
- (void)TS_commonButtonInit
{
    UIImage *shoutoutBackground            = [UIImage imageNamed:@"root-navigation-bar-share-button"];
    UIImage *shoutoutHighlightedBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"root-navigation-bar-share-button-highlighted"];
    UIImage *shoutoutPulseImage            = [UIImage imageNamed:@"root-navigation-bar-share-button-glowing"];

    shoutoutBackground            = [shoutoutBackground            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0];
    shoutoutHighlightedBackground = [shoutoutHighlightedBackground stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0];
    shoutoutPulseImage            = [shoutoutPulseImage            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0];

    [[self backgroundView] setImage:shoutoutBackground];
    [[self backgroundView] setHighlightedImage:shoutoutHighlightedBackground];

    [self setGlowingImage:shoutoutPulseImage];

    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];

    [self addSubview:[self backgroundView]];
    [self addSubview:[self glowingImageView]];

    [[self layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"ffc521" alpha:1] CGColor]];
    [[self layer] setShadowOpacity:0];
    [[self layer] setShadowRadius:5];
    [[self layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
    [[self layer] setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:[self bounds] cornerRadius:6] CGPath]];
}
```

**Pulsing Code:**

```
- (void)pulse:(NSInteger)numberOfTimes
{
    CGFloat pulseLength = .8;

    [[self glowingImageView] setAlpha:0];

    CABasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [pulseAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [pulseAnimation setDuration:pulseLength];
    [pulseAnimation setRepeatCount:numberOfTimes];
    [pulseAnimation setAutoreverses:YES];
    [pulseAnimation setFromValue:@(0)];
    [pulseAnimation setToValue:@(1)];
    [pulseAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];

    [[self layer] setShadowOpacity:0];

    CABasicAnimation *shadowAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
    [shadowAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [shadowAnimation setDuration:pulseLength];
    [shadowAnimation setRepeatCount:numberOfTimes];
    [shadowAnimation setAutoreverses:YES];
    [shadowAnimation setFromValue:@(0)];
    [shadowAnimation setToValue:@(1)];
    [shadowAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];

    [[[self glowingImageView] layer] addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
    [[self layer] addAnimation:shadowAnimation forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];
}
```